# Multi thread app hangs after executing onclickBtn

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, freeze

I'm writing a weather app in javaFx getting data from openweather.org. The whole code for getting JSON from openweather works fine, converting JSON data to an object too. I used lambda expression to implement `Runnable` in `Platform.runLater();`. The problem is: if I run the Main class, press the button, the app hangs. The thread for importing data works (checked by 2 prints on console) and the main thread "skips" `Platform.runLater();` and prints something on the console. I'm not sure what is wrong here.

my Controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Controller implements Observable{


        private static final WeatherStation WEATHER_STATION = new WeatherStation();
        protected volatile boolean isRunning = false;
        private String response;

    private static final int _5MINUTES = 1000*60*5;
    private volatile ArrayList<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();


    @FXML
    private TextField cityTextfield;

    @FXML
    private CategoryAxis xAxis;

    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis;

    @FXML
    private Button btn;

    @FXML
    private LineChart<String, Number> plot;

    @FXML
    void onclickBtn(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
        WeatherUpdater weatherUpdater = new WeatherUpdater(plot);
        setSettings();
        WeatherObserver wroclaw = new WeatherObserver();
        weatherUpdater.addObserver(wroclaw);

        Platform.runLater(()->{
            isRunning = true;
            while(isRunning) try {
                addObserver(wroclaw);
                PlotDataUpdater<String, Number> dataUpdater = new PlotDataUpdater<>();
                WEATHER_STATION.sendQuery();
                response = WEATHER_STATION.getCurrentResponse();
                updateObservers();
                WeatherConditions weatherConditions = observers.get(0).getWeatherConditions();

                LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.of(LocalTime.now().getHour(), LocalTime.now().getMinute());

                dataUpdater.updateSeries(currentTime.toString(), weatherConditions.getMainTemp());

                dataUpdater.updatePlot(plot);
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(_5MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
            }
        });

        System.out.println(".................................");
    }


    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        if(!observers.contains(observer)) observers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
        if(observers.contains(observer)) observers.remove(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObservers() {
        for(Observer o : observers){
            o.updateWeatherInfo(response);
        }
    }

    private void setSettings(){
        plot.getData().clear();
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
        plot.setAnimated(false);
    }

}
```

Classes used for generating plot data, converting things from JSON work as intended. If more code is needed, leave a comment.

@Edit: The code for a class implementing `Observable`, `Runnable` with own thread:

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WeatherUpdater implements Runnable, Observable{

    private Thread updater;
    private static final WeatherStation WEATHER_STATION = new WeatherStation();
    protected volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    private String response;
    private static final int _5MINUTES = 1000*60*5;
    private volatile ArrayList<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();
    private XYChart<String, Number> plot;

    public WeatherUpdater(XYChart<String, Number> plot) {
        this.plot = plot;
    }

    public WeatherUpdater() {

    }

    public void start(){
        updater = new Thread(this,"Weather updater");
        updater.start();
    }

    public void interrupt(){
        isRunning = false;
        updater.interrupt();
    }

    public XYChart<String, Number> getPlot() {
        return plot;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        isRunning = true;
        while(isRunning){
            try{
                PlotDataUpdater<String, Number> dataUpdater = new PlotDataUpdater<>();
                WEATHER_STATION.sendQuery();
                response = WEATHER_STATION.getCurrentResponse();
                updateObservers();
                WeatherConditions weatherConditions = observers.get(0).getWeatherConditions();

                LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.of(LocalTime.now().getHour(), LocalTime.now().getMinute());

                dataUpdater.updateSeries(currentTime.toString(), weatherConditions.getMainTemp());

                dataUpdater.updatePlot(plot);
                Thread.sleep(_5MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                updater.interrupt();
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted" );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        if(!observers.contains(observer)) observers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
        if(observers.contains(observer)) observers.remove(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateObservers() {
        for(Observer o : observers){
            o.updateWeatherInfo(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Modification of 'onclickBtn' method combined with the class above:

```
@FXML
    void onclickBtn(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
        WeatherUpdater weatherUpdater = new WeatherUpdater(plot);
        setSettings();
        WeatherObserver wroclaw = new WeatherObserver();
        weatherUpdater.addObserver(wroclaw);
        weatherUpdater.start();


        System.out.println(".................................");
    }
```

Console output:

```
.................................
Server status: 200
Exception in thread "Weather updater" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Weather updater
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:471)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.chart.LineChart.seriesAdded(LineChart.java:405)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.lambda$new$1(XYChart.java:160)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.setAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:90)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.setAll(ObservableListBase.java:251)
    at sample.PlotDataUpdater.updatePlot(PlotDataUpdater.java:36)
    at sample.WeatherUpdater.run(WeatherUpdater.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what [Plaftform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) is intended for. It's not for running background tasks, in fact it's the complete opposite: it's for delegating tasks to the JavaFX application thread (Or "main thread" in a JavaFX app for simplicity).

Based on your description I would guess that what you want to do is to fetch the data from the web API in a background thread so that it doesn't block the application. To do this you can use [JavaFX Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), note that in order to update the GUI afterwards you need to use [Plaftform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: I think you're right. But if I create a class implementing `Runnable` and `Observable`, put a `Thread` object as a field, implement `start`, `stop`, `interrupt`,   and then in method `oncklickBtn` create an instance of this class and start the thread, an exception is thrown: `Exception in thread "Weather updater" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`. Therefore I used `Platform.runLater`- simply the exception wasnt thrown and the data was taken from the website, but the app hanged.

Comment: You should only wrap the minimal GUI update code inside `Platform.runLater`, not the whole method. The reason it hangs is because of your loop (`while(isRunning`), which should be ran on a background thread. If you still have trouble, update your question with the new code.

Comment: I added the code, in which I use a separate class with its own thread to take this things out of website. I pasted the console output too.

Comment: These 2 lines: `dataUpdater.updateSeries(currentTime.toString(), weatherConditions.getMainTemp())` and `dataUpdater.updatePlot(plot)` should be wrapped inside `Platform.runLater`. I'm not certain if it's necessary to put the first one in `Platform.runLater`, but for cleaniness I would still put it there.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Why they need to be in `Platform.runLater`? It is because they update fields in controller? I just want to know for the future.

Comment: In JavaFX any update to the scene graph should be done on the JavaFX application thread for thread-safety reasons. Interestingly I couldn't find any official documents that mention this except in the documentation of `Task`. However, the concept of only allowing updating the GUI on the main thread is common in multiple programming languages and frameworks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184833/discussion-between-gnas-and-embid123).